# how to extract a text which is in hidden visibility mode?

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to extract Number of stars a book got from amazon.com . I tried doing it by Xpath , but it shows the error :-

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kbvt.png)/div/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kbvt.png)"}

Like as shown in image i want to extract the part :- "4.7 out of 5 stars" , but since it is visibility mode i am not able to extract the information.

Can anyone help me out ??
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an extension that gives you the XPath expression of an element on the page?

Comment: Yes , i am using Firebug , and it gives the Xpath

Comment: First click that down arrow with your selenium code and make it visible

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yeah, that text isn't invisible, it just hasn't been generated yet.

Comment: @RajeshKumar i didnt get your question .

Comment: We are able to see 4.7 out of 5 stars right? is that you manually clicked it? or with selenium code?

Comment: I want to get the information 4.7....5 from the selenium code , but i am unable to extract it by Xpath.

yes , i have manually clicked it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  I am unable to extract the information . Can you guide as to how to get "4.7...5" part ?? Even i am unable to extract the part which says 5stars :- 80% , 4stars:-15% ......

Comment: did you try clicking that down arrow with selenium code?

Comment: @RajeshKumar :- No

Comment: Try clicking that down arrow with selenium code and then check the xpath you will get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150496/discussion-between-gopal-chitalia-and-rajesh-kumar).

Comment: @GopalChitalia Could you privide the specific url?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A133140011&page=1&sort=salesrank&unfiltered=1&ie=UTF8

Comment: I have just tested my solution and it works. I give you my code sample.

Comment: @OscarMartinez I want to fetch all the ratings available in the page , but it is able to fetch for some books but not for all , any reason as to why this happens ? and any specific solution ?? It throws an error as to the element doesn't exist

Comment: Please post your new problem as a new question, it will be better. I will be glad to help you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is being shown when mouse hover over the element. Probably with an AJAX query. You need to perform a mouse hover and then, when it displays, catch the text.

1. To do this you need to import `ActionChains`

`from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`

2. Then perform the mouse hover:

`element_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath(...)
hover_action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover)
hover_action.perform()`

3. Once the element is displayed, you just find your text element by xpath.

(Perhaps you need to `time.sleep(1)` between step 2 and 3.)

**EDIT**

Already tested and it works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A133140011&page=1&sort=salesrank&unfiltered=1&ie=UTF8")

element_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span/a/i[1]/span""")
hover_action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover)
hover_action.perform()
time.sleep(2)
stars_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="a-popover-content-3"]/div/div/div/div[1]/span""")
print stars_count.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```